# Unable to compile a program on server which runs on my machine locally

Tags: mysql, c, database, portability

I have a project that compiles and runs on my system but when I try to run it on server it is giving compile-time errors. Here are the portion of the Makefile I use to compile it on my system:

```
CC =  gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall
COMPLILEFLAGS = `mysql_config --include`
LINKERINFO = `mysql_config --cflags --libs`

exec: main.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o exec main.o $(LINKERINFO)

main.o: main.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(COMPLILEFLAGS) -c main.c
```

When I run the same file on the server I get the following error:

```
gcc -g -Wall -I/usr/include/mysql -c main.c
In file included from main.c:13:
/usr/include/mysql/my_global.h:688: error: redefinition of typedef ‘my_bool’
/usr/include/mysql/mysql.h:55: note: previous declaration of ‘my_bool’ was here
In file included from main.c:13:
/usr/include/mysql/my_global.h:699: error: redefinition of typedef ‘my_socket’
/usr/include/mysql/mysql.h:69: note: previous declaration of ‘my_socket’ was here
In file included from main.c:13:
/usr/include/mysql/my_global.h:1102: error: redefinition of typedef ‘my_ulonglong’
/usr/include/mysql/mysql.h:132: note: previous declaration of ‘my_ulonglong’ was here
In file included from main.c:14:
/usr/include/mysql/my_getopt.h:64: warning: ‘enum loglevel’ declared inside parameter list
```

The main.c file is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#include <my_global.h>

int main (void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone suggest a possible work around this problem. All I want is to increase the portability of this code. One option I can think of is to make the files `compiler` and `linker` are using within my source and use them for compiling and linking.

By the way I am using mysql-server version 5.5 and server has mysql-server version 5.3

Comment: It sounds like something is wrong in `my_global.h`.  As we can't see the code, we can only guess.  You should construct a simple test-case, and post that.

Comment: `my_global.h` it is a library provided by mysql for client development(C API) so it is likely to have different version on each system and that I know and because of that my program runs on my machine and not on server. I think we are not supposed to look into the code of an API as as there will be no use of one if we have do so. Does my point makes sense?

Comment: Can you re-create this error with a five-line `foo.c` and five-line `Makefile`? (I expect you can.)

Comment: About the re-definitions erros, It sounds that `my_global.h/my_sqli.h` is including same file two or more times. We need background information, including a significant part code of this file. My suggestion is implement include guards. And  `my_getopt.h` I suggest you post here as this function is defined and declared in this header.

Comment: @TheMask the error is pretty clear to me but there are thousands of systems with thousand different version of these file. All I want is to make my code run on the servers without touching those header files because I didn't create them. Can there be some solution. Did you get my point of not seeing those files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at MySQL's documentation I found that [old versions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/building-clients.html) included a warning that stated that `my_global.h` should be included before `mysql.h` for compiling on Windows.

Try reversing the order of the includes and see if that fixes the issue. If it does, a bug is to be filed with MySQL urgently.

Comment: Thanks I will do and post the result here. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. It is kind of stupid that altering the order of files worked. Although no need to file a bug as it runs fine on I downloaded recently so may be they have fixed it already.

Comment: exactly the reason why I think it is a bug :S